# FAKE equivalent to Ant properties files?

Tags: f#, f#-fake

I'm converting a project from using NAnt to FAKE. The project is using a *.properties file to inform the main build.xml script of the locations of some executables that the build.xml script file will need to execute.

Due to the nature of these executables they are not easily discoverable because installation does not install them in PATH and the user is able to customize the location of where they are installed. Hence the *.properties files for users to set where they are located.

What would be the FAKE equivalent? I thought about having build parameters passed with each invocation of the FAKE build script but this isn't ideal because it requires them to remember what the build parameters are each time they want to run the build script. And having a build parameter be a long string which is the path to an executable is cumbersome to type each time anyway.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, FAKE does not have any built-in configuration system, but you can use any of the F# libraries for working with XML to read the configuration file. One nice option would be to use the XML type provider from [F# Data](http://fsharp.github.io/FSharp.Data/).

You'd need to make sure the `FSharp.Data` package is restored before FAKE is run (in the same way in which you're downloading FAKE). Then you can write `config.xml` looking like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <temp-folder>C:\temp</temp-folder>
  <executable>foo.exe</executable>
</configuration>
```

If you then add reference to F# Data and open the `FSharp.Data` namespace:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq.dll"
#r "packages/FSharp.Data/bin/FSharp.Data.dll"
open FSharp.Data
```

You can then use the XML provider. This can actually pick the names of the XML elements and makes them accessible as properties, so you get really nice access to the config:

```
type Config = XmlProvider<"config.xml"> // Assuming this is in the same folder
let config = Config.GetSample()

config.Executable
config.TempFolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the values for these custom paths in a .fsx file
Include this .fsx file in your main build script